# If statement not working even if the condition is true

Tags: c++

[This](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/multiply-strings/)  problem asks you to multiply two given strings. I know the logic and I have been implementing it. The logic is to follow old school multiplication technique. While debugging my code I am stuck in a very peculiar doubt where **if statement** doesn't gets executed even if its condition is true.

```
// Example program
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string multiply(string A, string B) {
    vector<string> s;

    for(int i=B.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        int sum=0, carry=0;
        string ans="";
        for(int j=A.size()-1; j>=0; j--){

            int sum = (A[j]-'0')*(B[i]-'0')+carry;

            carry = sum/10;

            sum = sum%10;
            ans += (sum + '0');
        }
        if(carry>0){
            ans += (carry + '0');
        }
        reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
        s.push_back(ans);
    }


    int maxx = INT_MIN;

    /*Concatenating adequate amount of zeroes to different lines */

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        int j=i;
        //cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        while(j--){
            s[i]+="0";
        }
        //cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        //cout<<s[i].size()<<endl;

        if(maxx < s[i].size()){
            cout<<"True"<<endl;
            maxx=s[i].size();
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Not true"<<endl;
        }
    }
    /*for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        cout<<s[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<maxx<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        int x=maxx-s[i].size();
        while(x--){
            s[i] = "0"+s[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        cout<<s[i]<<endl;
    }*/
    return "No answer";
}
int main()
{
    string ans = multiply("1234","567");
    return 0;
}
```

I have doubt in **if statement** of this part:

```
for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        int j=i;
        //cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        while(j--){
            s[i]+="0";
        }
        //cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        //cout<<s[i].size()<<endl;

        if(maxx < s[i].size()){
            cout<<"True"<<endl;
            maxx=s[i].size();
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Not true"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

I printed **s[i].size()** value and **maxx** value just before the if statement. Initially s[i].size() is greater than maxx. But still the output printed is **Not True** instead of being **True**.

You can copy paste the code into your computer for debugging. Its completely working code.

I have been stuck on it for a long time. Kindly suggest due to what weird reason is that statement not working.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although it is marked as duplicate, you can try add cast on size() `maxx < (int) s[i].size()` to see.

Comment: Thanks it worked. However, the conclusion is "Comparing signed and unsigned integers can give unexpectedly surprising results"?..Is it so?

Comment: Yes. The signed integer will be added `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() + 1` to cast to the size_t, which is a unsigned. It may be very large number instead of negative integer.